# What's the word when you learn something good unintentionally accidentally along the way stuff?

Tags: nouns

I forgot, it was such an exact definition!@!@!

Comment: Can you give an example of "when you learn something good unintentionally accidentally along the way stuff"?

Comment: It's 'serendipitous', and this is a duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Word or phrase for mere coincidence that brings happiness](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96583/word-or-phrase-for-mere-coincidence-that-brings-happiness) Or [word or phrase for random learning through ...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/274567/word-or-phrase-for-random-learning-through-linked-documents)? Or [a ... word that is used when one finds something unexpectedly](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/475852/a-short-word-that-is-used-when-one-finds-something-unexpectedly/475912#475912)?